# How to convert list to map in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm new to dart. I'm trying to covert my Holiday class to Map to be used in my calendar. I tried using `Map.fromIterable` but it only convert it to `<String, dynamic>`?

```
class Occasion {
  final List<Holiday> holidays;


  Map<DateTime, List> toMap() {
    var map = Map.fromIterable(holidays,
        key: (e) => DateFormat('y-M-d').format(DateTime.parse(e.date)),
        value: (e) => e.name);
    print(map);
  }
}

class Holiday {
  final String date;
  final String name;

  Holiday({
    this.date,
    this.name,
  });

  factory Holiday.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Holiday(date: parsedJson['date'], name: parsedJson['name']);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with the line?: var outputMap = new Map.fromIterable(holidays, key: (v) => v[0], value: (v) => v[1]);

Comment: Where does the problem appear in this snippet? I have some suggestions anyway: First, your toMap doesn't return anything. and second you can give the Map.fromIterable some more type information `Map<DateTime, List<String>>`. 
Also give oyur List more type information on what it contains.

Comment: @Saskia, the problem is when i return it. `A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic> can't be returned from method 'toMap' because it has a return type of 'Map<DateTime, List>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things:
First: The type parameters of your returned map aren't right for the values you produce in `fromIterable`. You say it should be List, but in `value: ...` you are only producing a single String.

Secondly, as I said in my comment you need to help out the dart compiler here a little bit. The compiler isn't very smart. It doesn't see that you are only producing Strings in value. You need to tell him that.

To be fair. This might not be the problem of the compiler, but an overuse of the dynamic type in the collections library.

```dart
  Map<String, String> toMap() {
    var map = Map<String, String>.fromIterable(holidays,
        key: (e) => e.date,
        value: (e) => e.name );
    return map;
  }
```

Just remember: be precise with your types. If you run into type errors start putting additional type information everywhere you can. If you feel it's to cluttered after that, try removing them one spot at a time and see where it leads you.

Comment: I thought you are just refering to the first return Map. I didn't even know that you can add a cast before `fromIterable`. But now I know, thanks.

Comment: It's not a cast. You specify what the type parameters of the map are. I guess the benefit (if you want to call it that) is that you can have all kings of types as values in your map. just like in javascript.
You just lose a lot of the typesafety by using dynamic and need to rely on type cast on call sites.